# delphi 10.2 уведомления в windows 10 как?

Tags: windows, delphi

На официальном сайте delphi http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Tokyo/en/VCL.Windows_10_Notifications_Sample я вижу пример по работе уведомлений. Все работает. НО это довольно простой пример. На сколько я знаю API windows  позволяет гораздо больше возможностей: с картинкой, с кнопками, отложенные, и тд тп... 
вот тут показано: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tiles_and_toasts/2015/07/08/toast-notification-and-action-center-overview-for-windows-10/

Подскажите как это все делать?

Comment: Список возможностей для каждой платформы: [Using Notifications](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Using_Notifications) - причём, это **все** возможности. Больше пока не реализовано. Вы всегда можете открыть сорцы класса `TNotification` (`System.Notification.pas`) и пересчитать по пальцам доступные возможности.

Comment: хорошо, ну а как можно реализовать расширенные уведомления можете посоветовать?

Comment: @zed в случае, если редакция делфей поставляется с исходниками. в стартер версии только dcu должны быть

Comment: используйте сторонние компоненты, либо работайте напрямую с интерфейсами, которые предоставляет ОС, если родные компоненты делфей не предоставляют такой возможности.

Comment: подскажите какие еще есть сторонние компоненты

Comment: @teran В Community Edition лишь **некоторые** юниты поставляются не в сорцах, большинство же юнитов, в том числе и обсуждаемый, идёт в сорцах.

Comment: да я уже поставил не комьюнити, полную, как быть? там тоже урезано и только простой пример уведомления вижу на одном шаблоне

Comment: @АлексЛизенберг Ничего там не "урезано", просто это всё что есть. А как быть, вам уже ответили - ищите сторонний компонент или берите документацию по WinAPI и делайте всё руками. Это очевидный алгоритм действий, когда Delphi "из коробки" чем-то не устраивает.

Comment: @АлексЛизенберг [Судя по всему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/900689), вы разобрались, как делать сложные уведомления (как минимум с кнопками). Не хотите опубликовать тут ответ с примером кода?

Comment: Да) опубликую, надо еще как то с реакциями на нажатие разобраться

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вобщем разобрался с уведомлениями, оказалось, что встроенная библиотека в делфи Tnotification - позволяет только попробовать уведомления на простом примере, в остальном пришлось разбираться с помощью документации microsoft. Но я все равно еще не до конца разобрался - как получать реакцию на события. Как делать сложные уведомления (с картинками и кнопками) я разобрался.

Мне показалось, что компонент, который в делфи, довольно сильно усложняет понимание как работает уведомление. На самом деле, фактически уведомление windows 10 - это XML документ

Вот базовый шаблон:

```
<toast>
  <visual>
    <binding template="ToastGeneric">
      тут указываем текст и картинку
    </binding>
  </visual>
  <actions>
     тут указываем кнопки
  </actions>
</toast>
```

Как я добился, я сначала хотел найти, так сказать чистый код, чисто на  winapi, чтобы просто формировать свой документ и передавать напрямую, но мне не удалось заставить работать этот код:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32105337/how-to-add-a-text-node-to-a-toast-notification

Тогда я скопировал исходные коды компонента в папку проекта и стал исправлять нужные мне функции, т.к. если я изменял компонент в папке исходников - изменения не работали...

Как я поступил:
я сам формирую нужный мне XML и передаю его  в компонент уведомления, для этого я изменил функцию в компоненте, чтобы она принимала мой код

```
class function TToastTemplateGenerator.GetXMLDoc(const ANotification
  : TNotification): Xml_Dom_IXmlDocument;
// ...
begin
  // LTemplateType := SelectTemplate;
  Result :=  ANotification.Template;
  // Result := TToastNotificationManager.Statics.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastText01);
  // остальной код функции можно закомментить
```

Ну и в класс уведомления, я добавил поле с шаблоном

```
  TNotification = class(TPersistent)
    // ...
    Title: string;
    Template: Xml_Dom_IXmlDocument;
```

Ну и теперь моя функция вызова уведомления выглядит так:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyNotification: TNotification; //Defines a TNotification variable
  XML: String;
  hXML: HString;
begin

  XML :=
    '<toast activationType="protocol" launch="https://www.santa.ru" duration="short">' +
    '<visual>                                                                                       ' +
    '  <binding template="ToastGeneric">                                                             ' +
    '    <image placement="appLogoOverride" hint-crop="circle" src="file:///d:\downloads\santa.jpg"/> ' +
    '      <text hint-maxLines="1">Adaptive Tiles Meeting</text>                                    ' +
    '      <text>Conf Room 2001 / Building 135</text>                                              ' +
    '      <text>10:00 AM - 10:30 AM</text>                                                        ' +
    '      <image src="file:///d:\downloads\ketrin.jpg"/>                                          ' +
    '  </binding>                                                                                  ' +
    '</visual>                                                                                     ' +
    '  <actions>                                                                                    ' +
    '  <action content="Open Google" activationType="protocol" arguments="http://www.google.com"/>  ' +
    '  <action content="Open 2" activationType="protocol" arguments="http://yandex.ru"/>          ' +
    '</actions>                                                                           ' +
    '</toast>' ;


  MyNotification := NotificationCenter1. CreateNotification; //Creates the notification
  try
    MyNotification.Name := 'Windows10Notification'; //Defines the name of the notification. 
    MyNotification.Template := str_to_XML (XML);

    NotificationCenter1.PresentNotification(MyNotification); //Presents the notification on the screen.
  finally 
    MyNotification.Free; //Frees the variable
  end;
end;
```

вспомогательные функции

```
function HStr(Value: String): HString;
begin
  if NOT Succeeded(WindowsCreateString(PWideChar(Value), Length(Value), Result))
  then
    raise Exception.CreateFmt('Unable to create HString for %s', [Value]);
end;

function str_to_XML(Const XML: String): Xml_Dom_IXmlDocument;
var
  hXML: HString;
begin
  Result :=  TToastNotificationManager.Statics.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastText01);
  hXML := HStr(XML);
  try
    (Result as Xml_Dom_IXmlDocumentIO).LoadXml(hXML);
  finally
    WindowsDeleteString(hXML);
  end;
end;
```

С реакцией на нажатие я пытаюсь разобраться в этом вопросе [Реакция на actions уведомлений windows 10 на delphi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/900689/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-actions-%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-windows-10-%D0%BD%D0%B0-delphi), ищу решение.
Как найду обязательно расскажу