# Реакция на actions уведомлений windows 10 на delphi

Tags: windows, delphi

Разобрался наконец с шаблонами xml уведомлений winapi.notification, там есть кнопки, action, при нажатии на них можно указать обработчик. Вот пример с сайта делфи

```
procedure TNotificationsForm.NotificationCenter1ReceiveLocalNotification(Sender: TObject;
  ANotification: TNotification);
begin
  mmLog.Lines.Add('Notification received: ' + ANotification.Name); //Shows the name of the notification handled.
end;
```

Но это реакция на любое нажатие, хоть на кнопку, хоть на само уведомление.

Подскажите как обработать конкретнее по чему нажали?

еще как то можно подписываться на событие через

```
LAccepted := TAcceptedEventHandler.Create;
LToast.add_Activated(LAccepted);
```

нашел это тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32105337/how-to-add-a-text-node-to-a-toast-notification, но я не могу найти этит тип TAcceptedEventHandler, какой модуль подключить, чтобы объявить этот тип? Искал по исходникам, ничего не нашло....

Comment: То что вы нашли на SO это из сорцов старой презентации (2015 года) Marco Cantu [Windows 10 Notifications from a VCL app with the WinRT API](http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/2015-june-windows10-notifications-vcl-winrt.html)

Comment: это все устарело? как тогда сделать обработку?

Comment: Я не в курсе, устарело оно или нет. Для начала поставьте себе заголовочники WinRT как написано с статье (если ещё не поставили) и поищите нужные классы и интерфейсы там.

Comment: запускаю менеджер getit, ввожу в поиске winRT - ничего не найдено

Comment: вобщем я нашел в коде, где идет подписка на событие, навярника там передается сообщение, но как дебагом посмотреть переменную? там переменная типа Tmassage навожу на нее и там () все... я обычно привык, например, на питоне или js, всю структуру объекта видно, что где как и сразу видно где лежит нужная тебе информация